# Why the file/memory size of picture doesn't depend on the number of pixels?

Tags: image, graphics

Why the size of every 1024 X 768 image (or any two or more images of same resolution)  is not fixed ? while they've same number of pixels ?

Comment: Because different content in your images will achieve different amounts of compression.

Comment: what about uncompressed image ?

Comment: What format are your images?

Comment: mine are in .bmp format, I've came to know images with this extension are uncompressed, apart from this, I'm generally talking

Comment: Well, some are 8-bit, some are 16-bit, some are 24-bit. Some are palletised, some are true-colour. Some are RLE compressed. Some are Huffman coded. Some have transparency some don't.

Comment: Understood, but what thiNg makes the size of every image (off course I'm talking about of same resolutions) different ?

Comment: E.G When I captures images from my cell fone came 8 MP camera, every image has different size

Comment: Your cellphone captures JPEGs not BMPs, surely? And different contrasts, lighting, content... all compress differently. Post some images if you want a properly reasoned answer rather than a general discussion.

Comment: I'll be very thankful to you, if you explain me with some real life example, or an analogy, I'm still confused, if the contents of images are compressed differently, but the number of pixel remains the same, what causes it to change the size ?
Cheers

Comment: @AhsanAlii imagine two pictures: one with every pixel in different color, one all black. You can describe black image with only few bytes - every pixel has the same color. Read about jpeg compression here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because most image formats compress the image, so that its size depends on its content.  Also, there are many options to most image formats, so even if they are uncompressed, a different image writer may produce a different file size for the same image.

Raw image formats (say for high-end digital cameras) are usually uncompressed; you might expect that raw-formatted images from the same camera at the same resolution setting would all have the same size.